# Rename files based on SQL query

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have a table with filenames in it and also a userID for the person whose file it is. What I need to do is rename the file so that the userID is in the name of the file. The file right now might be `01234_main1.3gp` and the user might be `987654` so I would want it to become `987654_main1.3gp`.

What I have below renames the files to `system.Data.Datarow+_main1.3gp`. I know the variable works, immediately before the rename command I do a `Write-Output` and the correct number sequence is there.

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -Name -Path 'c:\main1'

foreach ($item in $items) {
    $Query = @"
SELECT [su_ID] as $SU_ID
FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
WHERE (assetLog_m1audio = '$item')
"@

    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance surveyname -Database database -Query $Query

    Write-Output $su_ID

    Rename-Item C:\main1\$item $su_ID+'_main1.3gp'
}
```

Comment: I would be quite surprised if your code snippet actually did what you claim it does (have `SELECT [su_ID] as $SU_ID` return the value of the field `su_ID` as the variable `$SU_ID`). Last time I checked that is not what the keyword `AS` does in a select list. Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're facing (when run from a clean PowerShell instance), [edit] your question and post *that* code.

Comment: Interesting, I guess I could include a screen shot but the write-output DOES return the variable $su_ID. As is a perfectly valid SQL statement. I originally used this line instead, which also returns using write-output but does not use as:              $sID = (Invoke-SQLCMD -ServerInstance servername -Database databasename -Query $Query)